# Ignore map click if marker clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, leaflet

I want if event occurs on the marker, then stop the event map.
I use mouseDown event for marker, and eventUp for map.

If I clicked on marker, then open div block, but if I click on map, then close div block. Now I clicked on marker, it onep div block and block immediately closes.

Use additional variable is not good, because div block may be under the cursor and mouseUp event on map don't run.

[image]

[image]

Summarizing: if I click on marker, map event doesn't run.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want the click to bubble up, you can use [`.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/):

```
$('#marker').on('mousedown', function(e){
    // Do whatever you like
    // This is the 'normal' part of the code
}).on('mouseup', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation(); // stop the mouseup
});
```

> **Description**: Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree,
>   preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Comment: e.stopPropagation() blocked mousedown, but don't blocked mouseup. Marker use event - mousedown, but map use event mouseup. If map use mousedown, event is blocked. How blocked mouseup through the event mousedown?

Comment: mouseup absent in marker =( And on('mouseup') don't work =( [link](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker) http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker I will use mobile browser and event click is no. I must use mouseup and mousedown, because touchstart and touchend